# How to Customize an individual Field in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

This is my ArticleType.php

```html
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('tags')
            ->add('cover')
            ->add('is_recommend', null, array('attr'=>array('require' => true)))
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }
```

how to customize filed "cover" in twig? this is my code in twig

```html
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
        {% form_theme edit_form with 'AppsAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'%}

        {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form) }}

        {% block _article_cover_widget %}
            <div class="text_widget">
                {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
                <a href="">上传文件</a>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {{ form_end(edit_form) }}

    </div><!-- /.col -->
```

I want customize field cover in this twig, but, I don't know, why it's not work, I hope get help, thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to 'change' exactly?

Comment: {% block _article_cover_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Comment: it's not work, {{ block('form_widget_simple') }} is empty in div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) to customize form rendering.

If you want to manage each field rendering separately, you can do it this way too:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
{% form_theme edit_form with 'AppsAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'%}

        {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form) }}

        {{ form_row(edit_form.title) }}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.category) }}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.tags) }}
        <div class="text_widget">
                {{ form_row(edit_form.cover) }}
                <a href="">上传文件</a>
        </div>        
        {{ form_row(edit_form.is_recommend) }}                        
        {{ form_row(edit_form.description) }}                                

        {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
</div>
```

or, simply:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
{% form_theme edit_form with 'AppsAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'%}

        <div class="text_widget">
                {{ form_row(edit_form.cover) }}
                <a href="">上传文件</a>
        </div>                                       
        {{ form_rest(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
</div>
```

Comment: you welcome, @Hubery. Feel free to accept my answer, :-)